# What is the C# equivalent to this Python?

Tags: c#, python

[Originating from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277401/generating-all-possible-permutations-for-a-given-base-and-number-of-digits), what would be the C# equivalent to this code? I think the `**` is the exponent, but I don't know what `[i]` does.

```
def sequence(v, p, column):
    subsequence = []
    for i in range(v):
        subsequence += [i] * v**(p - column)
    return subsequence * v**(column - 1)
```

Comment: `[i]` creates a python `list` containing `i` which allows you to use the `+=` operator to append to the `subsequence` list.

Comment: This is sort of beside the point, but are you sure this code is actually a good way to solve the original problem in the other thread? It generates the desired sequence column-wise, which seems counterintuitive and requires more work to join the thing together and think about how many columns there are.

Comment: @ggorlen, no, but it's the best I could find. I'd be grateful to learn of other options if you know of any.

Comment: I'll probably add an answer to the other thread--I'm not satisfied with the one that's there. I like the problem, though.

Comment: OK, I added a solution in the other thread. I wrote it in Python but I'll translate it to C# momentarily--the code is a lot more straightforward than the existing answer, I hope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One could do:

```
public static List<int> sequence(int v, int p, int column) {
  var subsequence = new List<int>();
  for (int i = 0; i < v; i++) {
    int limit = (int)Math.Pow(v, p - column);
    for (int j = 0; j < limit; j++)
      subsequence.Add(i);
  }

  var true_sequence = new List<int>();
  for (int k = 0; k < (int)Math.Pow(v, column - 1); k++)
    true_sequence.AddRange(subsequence);

  return true_sequence;
}
```

`[i] * <number>` is notation for "repeat this list `<number>` times and put the result in a new list". `[i]` is just a list containing only the number `i`.

Edit: Explanation

```
for i in range(v):
```

translates well to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < v; i++) {
```

```
subsequence += [i] * v**(p - column)
```

This is a bit complicated, but what it essentially says is "take v, take it to the power of (p - column), and then add that number of `i` to subsequence". This is close to that:

```
int limit = Math.Pow(v, p - column);
for (int j = 0; j < limit; j++)
  subsequence.Add(i);
```

```
return subsequence * v**(column - 1)
```

Now what this says is "take v to the power of (column - 1), and return a list containing that many instances of subsequence." That's what the rest of the code in the function does: takes Math.Pow(v, column - 1) subsequences, adds them all to a list, and returns said list.